# increament by 5 for loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop

I want to display some number in a dropdown options with the increment `5` which will be started to `5` and ended at `1005`. The result should be `5, 10, 15, .... 1000, 1005`.

So I wrote the loop as

```
<?php for ($i=5; $i < 1005; $i++) { ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>  
<?php } ?>
```

But it gives me as `5,6,7,....` . How can I resolve it?

Comment: $i+=5 instead of $i++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php for ($i=5; $i < 1005; $i+=5) { ?>
    <option value = "<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>  
<?php } ?>
```

`$i+=5` <-- This is the only change.

How about this?